# Elements scrolling over menu bar when menu bar is fixed

Tags: html, css, menu, menubar

Summary:I would like my menu-bar to be fixed(which I have achieved),but I am having a problem in which during scrolling,the content move over the fixed menu bar instead of it going under the menu-bar.
 I have checked different sites and I saw a related question here on SO [CSS - Make Content Appear Beneath a Fixed DIV Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402635/css-make-content-appear-beneath-a-fixed-div-element)
but it doesn't work for me and I am wondering why?.
  Here is my html code:

```
      <!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link href="fixed.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="fixed-bar" width="1333" height="48" border="0" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td width="96" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>

                <td><hsso style="font:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-shadow:#0C0 0.1em 0.1em 0.3em; color:#030; font-size:32px; text-align:center;"> Fixed Bar.</hsso></td>
        <td><a class="linear" href="signup">
                <span>Sign Up </span>

            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td  class="nav-bar1" align="left">   



        </td>
        <td width="158" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
        <div style="height: 80px; width: 100%;"></div> 
 <table width="361" height="891" border="0" align="center" class="tab1" >
    <tr>
        <td width="467" align="center"><input placeholder="Username" autocomplete="on" class="inp" type="text" name="un" id="un"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><input placeholder="Password" autocomplete="on" class="inp" type="text" name="pw" id="pw"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><input placeholder="Re-enter Password" autocomplete="on" class="inp" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><input placeholder="First Name" autocomplete="on" class="inp" type="text" name="fn" id="fn"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><input placeholder="Last Name" autocomplete="on" class="inp" type="text" name="ln" id="ln"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><select class="sel"   name="st"  id="st">
        <option>Please Select your Set</option>
        <option>1997/1998</option>
        <option>1998/1999</option>
        <optiom>1999/2000</optiom>
        <option>2001/2002</option>
        <option>2002/2003</option>
        <option>2003/2004</option>
        <option>2005/2006</option>
        <option>2006/2007</option>
        <option>2007/2008</option>
        <option>2008/2009</option>
        <option>2009/2010</option>
        <option>2010/2011</option>
        <option>2011/2012</option>
        <option>2012/2013</option>

      </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td  align="center"><input placeholder="Email" autocomplete="on" class="inp" type="text" name="em" id="em"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><input class="reg" type="submit" name="reg" id="reg" value="     Register     "></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my CSS:

```
table.fixed-bar{
      box-shadow:#0C0 0.1em 0.2em 0.5em 0.1em;
    border-radius: 8px;
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    left: 0; 
    clear: both;

}
table.tab1{
     border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow:#0C0 0.1em 0.2em 0.5em 0.1em;  

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give `.fixed-bar` a higher `z-index`.

`.fixed-bar {
    z-index: 1000;
}`

Answer (score 1):

You have got no background assigned to the fixed position element.

Try giving it a background color and it shouldn't be transparent anymore.

```
background:#fff;
```

SOLUTION:

http://jsfiddle.net/8T2zt/

Comment: Thanks,it works well.But it doesnt work on my real project,even after adding the background property.Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Is your real project hosted? Or is it local? It should work, unless you are not saving the files after updating them.

Answer (score 1):

I had to had both the z-index property,giving it a high value and also set the background property.